# Am I passing a variable to a method correctly?

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a chunk of jQuery that isn't *quite* behaving the way I expect.

I'm taking the selected value from an HTML dropdown and storing it in a variable. The variable is then used to select an HTML element ID.

Here's the `<select>` I'm using for the dropdown:

```
<select id="bubble-tea-flavor" class="" name="attribute_bubble-tea-flavor" data-attribute_name="attribute_bubble-tea-flavor" data-show_option_none="yes">
     <option value="">Choose an option</option>
     <option value="Kiwi Apple" >Kiwi Apple</option>
     <option value="Peach Mango" >Peach Mango</option>
     <option value="Pineapple Peach" >Pineapple Peach</option>
</select>
```

Here are the HTML tags I am trying to target:

```
                <rs-slides>
                    <rs-slide data-key="rs-1" data-title="pineapplepeach" data-anim="ms:1000ms;" data-in="o:0;" data-out="a:false;" class="pineapplepeach" id="pineapplepeach">
                        ...
                    </rs-slide>
                    <rs-slide data-key="rs-3" data-title="peachmango" data-in="o:0;" data-out="a:false;" class="peachmango" id="peachmango">
                        ...
                    </rs-slide>
                    <rs-slide data-key="rs-4" data-title="kiwiapple" data-anim="ms:1000ms;" data-in="o:0;" data-out="a:false;" class="kiwiapple" id="kiwiapple">
                        ...
                    </rs-slide>
                </rs-slides>
```

Here is the jQuery snippet:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#bubble-tea-flavor" ).change( function() {
        var slide = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        console.log(slide);
        var selectedFlavorID = slide.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
        console.log(selectedFlavorID);

        revapi1.revcallslidewithid(selectedFlavorID);
    });
});
```

It *definitely* works to some extent. The console log shows the value is being captured and modified correctly:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2
(index):290 Peach Mango
(index):292 peachmango
(index):290 Pineapple Peach
(index):292 pineapplepeach
(index):290 Kiwi Apple
(index):292 kiwiapple
```

But then... nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Or, since this is for Revolution Slider and is probably more complicated than I'm thinking about it, how do I use Chrome to see what's happening when `revapi1.revcallslidewithid(selectedFlavorID);` is called?

For reference, here is the entire `<script>` tag where my snip comes from:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                setREVStartSize({c: 'rev_slider_1_1',rl:[1240,1024,778,480],el:[900],gw:[1240],gh:[900],type:'standard',justify:'',layout:'fullscreen',offsetContainer:'',offset:'',mh:"0"});
                var revapi1,
                    tpj;
                function revinit_revslider11() {
                jQuery(function() {
                    tpj = jQuery;
                    revapi1 = tpj("#rev_slider_1_1");
                    if(revapi1==undefined || revapi1.revolution == undefined){
                        revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("rev_slider_1_1");
                    }else{
                        revapi1.revolution({
                            sliderLayout:"fullscreen",
                            visibilityLevels:"1240,1024,778,480",
                            gridwidth:1240,
                            gridheight:900,
                            enableUpscaling:true,
                            perspective:600,
                            perspectiveType:"global",
                            editorheight:"900,768,960,720",
                            responsiveLevels:"1240,1024,778,480",
                            progressBar: {
                                style:"vertical",
                                horizontal:"center",
                                vertical:"top",
                                size:5
                            },
                            navigation: {
                                onHoverStop:false
                            },
                            fallbacks: {
                                allowHTML5AutoPlayOnAndroid:true
                            },
                        });
                        jQuery(function($) {
$( "#bubble-tea-flavor" ).change( function() {
    var slide = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    console.log(slide);
    var selectedFlavorID = slide.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    console.log(selectedFlavorID);

    revapi1.revcallslidewithid(selectedFlavorID);
});
});
                    }
                    
                });
                } // End of RevInitScript
            var once_revslider11 = false;
            if (document.readyState === "loading") {document.addEventListener('readystatechange',function() { if((document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") && !once_revslider11 ) { once_revslider11 = true; revinit_revslider11();}});} else {once_revslider11 = true; revinit_revslider11();}
            </script>
```